# FileOpenPicker + Facebook + OpenAsync throw FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have problem with FileOpenPicker (ModernUI xaml/c#) as in case of some pictures picked from the web it return "StorageFile" without error, but when I try to open it with OpenAsync then system throws FileNotFoundException. In particular I've noticed that this happens all the time in case of picking up old pictures from facebook.

It easy to reproduce that problem by using [SDK Sample app "XAML images sample"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9). Just start the app and pick-up some picture from "Facebook" and ensure to pick-up some old picture as I've noticed that latest one are opening just fine.

To be more specific please find the peace of code which actually throw's that exception:

```
    // Open a stream for the selected file
    StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

    // Ensure a file was selected
    if (file != null)
    {
        // Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
        // !!! Here exception is thrown if you pickup some old file from facebook !!!
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = decodePixelHeight;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = decodePixelWidth;

            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            Scenario2Image.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions and help

kind regards

MG

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here it go :)

When you download a file and save it somewhere on disc you can't open it after you`ll close it cause location isn't in app capabilities and remember that Windows Store Apps are sandboxed so they can get only that what is in capabilities.

You can manage with this "problem" in 2 ways.

1) Save the file in one of the places that your app can have access:
-> documents library
-> music library 
-> video library
-> image library
-> local app directory

Libraries can be set in capabilities to local app directory your app has always access. From those directories you can easly open file

2) save tha path to file in acces cache
You can do it like this

```
StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(fol.GetHashCode().ToString(), fol);
```

After that you can access the directory even if it isn't in place from your capabilities BUT remember that cache can contain 1000 directories